# Alexandrescu 'vexing alligator' allocator implementation?

Tags: library, software-development, c++, memory-management

In last year's CppCon, the wonderful Andrei Alexandrescu gave a talk on designing memory allocators, (in?)aptly named:

[std::allocator is to Allocation what std::vector is to Vexation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U)

(earlier titles: "std::allocator is to Allocation what allegator is to allegation" or "writing allocators which don't not-work").

Now, I'm not looking for a copy of his code, but rather something based on it, which:

- Has proper/better support for alignment (hopefully via template parameters, perhaps even including the alignment in the `Blk` structure?).
- Incorporates a richer variety of known allocation algorithms
- Is used by more than 2 people :-)

Is there such a thing out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is: Felix Petriconi's

[Allocator Builder library](https://github.com/FelixPetriconi/AllocatorBuilder) (GitHub)

Quoting from the repository description:

> A highly composable, policy based C++ allocator.
>
> The layout idea of the library is was presented by [Andrei Alexandrescu](http://erdani.com/)
>   at the [C++ and Beyond 2013](http://cppandbeyond.com/) seminar and at the [CppCon 2015](http://cppcon2015.sched.org/event/95b6c3282248b7e2595c5c3182d7652b).

So just what OP asked for. Additional general information:

- **Price**: Gratis.
- **License**: The [Boost software license](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:Boost1.0).
- **Started**: October 2014
- **Last commit**: April 2016

The composable allocators provided as of March 2017 are:

- **affix_allocator**: Allows to automatically pre- and sufix allocated regions.
- **allocator_with_stats**: An allocator that collects a configured number of statistic information, like number of allocated bytes, number of successful expansions and high tide
- **bucketizer**:   Manages a bunch of Allocators with increasing bucket size
- **fallback_allocator**:   Either the default Allocator can handle a request, otherwise it is passed to a fall-back Allocator
- **(aligned_)mallocator**:     Provides and interface to systems ::malloc(), the aligned variant allocates according to a given alignment
  null_allocator  An Null allocator
- **segregator**:   Separates allocation requests depending on a threshold to Allocator A or B
- **(shared_)freelist**:    Manages a list of freed memory blocks in a list for faster re-usage. (The Shared variant is thread safe)
- **(shared_)cascading_allocator**: Manages in a thread safe way Allocators and automatically creates a new one when the previous are out of memory. (The Shared variant is thread safe, but it needs further improvements, because it does not frees unused allocators)
- **(shared_)heap**: A heap block based heap. (The Shared variant is thread safe manner with minimal overhead and as far as possible in a lock-free way.)
- **stack_allocator**: Provides a memory access, taken from the stack

So it's a solid base to start off of. Lots of GitHub 'stars' and followers, too.